# "Allow loose classpath" checkbox in RAD

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere

In Rational Application Developer 7.5 under Preferences -> Java EE there's a checkbox with the label, "Allow loose classpath module dependencies (not recommended)". What does that checkbox do, and under what sort of circumstances would I want to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAD7.5 [initially missed the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM06294) on that particular option.

> Rational Application Developer v7.5 Help - Documentation needed for Preferences - Java EE : Loose classpath module dependencies [ ] Allow loose classpath module dependencies (not recommended)

The [RAD Help Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp) now includes a ["loose classpath" page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jee5.doc/topics/tlooseclasspath.html)

> Loose classpath support is an optional mechanism that allows for the inclusion of Eclipse Java development Tools classpath artifacts in a dynamic Web project's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
>   You can add dependencies using the Java EE Module Dependencies page, but you can also add the Web libraries from the Libraries page under the Java Build Page.
>   You can include Jars, external Jars, libraries, and variables.
>   The project validator now detects loose classpath issues and reports them in the problems view.

[image]